# How to extract a value from json using angular?

Tags: angularjs

How do i extract 57 from this json  [{"status":57}] in angular?

I have tried JSON.parse('{"status":57}').status but produces an error.

Comment: var_name[0].status

Comment: Please show more code context...where you get the json from and what you want to do with it.  See [mcve]. Also if something throws error... give full details of that error. Error messages are meaningful

Answer (score 1):

[{"status":57}] is already an array / array of object

you just need to extract the value

```
data = [{"status":57}];
data[0].status
```

Comment: well actually your first statement is incorrect because by definition json is a string. Saying it is already an array or object would be more accurate

Comment: @kiro112 the point is that JSON is string data-interchange format. When you use JSON.parse() you then take the JSON (string) and convert to javascript object. Many many people call an object a JSON object but that's not accurate and there is no such thing

Comment: i think i got it wrong too @charlietfl i always call it json / json object, thanks for pointing it out ! from now on ill call it array / object

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) to deserialize JSON strings:

```
angular.fromJson([{"status":57}])[0].status;
```